# how to check port number in url string?

Tags: javascript

Can I check whether the port number is existing in a given URL string or not?

Like sometimes a user can type `202.567.89.254:8088` or `http://202.567.89.254:8088/` or `http://202.567.89.254`.

Out of all the above options, if the port number is existing, then do nothing otherwise append `8080` by default with an end slash `8080/`.

Is it possible in JavaScript?

Answer (score 9):

You can try to use the [location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) object and use:

```
location.port
```

> The HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils.port property is a USVString containing
>   the port number of the URL.

Answer (score 5):

Here you go the easiest way, set the `href` attribute.

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = "http://example.com:3000/pathname/?search=test#hash";


console.log(parser.protocol); // => "http:"
console.log(parser.hostname); // => "example.com"
console.log(parser.port);     // => "3000"
console.log(parser.pathname); // => "/pathname/"
console.log(parser.host);     // => "example.com:3000"
```

read more [here](https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561)

Answer (score 4):

You can use location.port property.

```
  if(location.port){//then there is port}
  else{//No port}
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this works for you:

```
function appendPort(url){
    if(!url.match(/\:\d+$/)){
        return url + ":8080";
    }
}
```

If you want to do that on user entered location:

```
if(!location.port){
    location.port = 8080; // doing this will take care of rest of the URL component
}
```

:)

Comment: Change `":8080"` to `":8080/"` as it's requested on question.

Answer (score 1):

**Try below code**

```
urlSplit = url.split(":")
if(urlSplit.length==3){
    port  = urlSplit[2];
}
else{
   port  = 80;
}
```

Comment: Please note, that when using https protocol, default port is 443, not 80.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)

`Location.port` will serve your purpose

Answer (score 1):

use `location.port`.  Sample example below.

```
function appendPort(){
  if(location.port.length === 0){
    location.host = location.host + ":8080/";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
  if(location.port){
    //then there is port
    //you may alert() if you want
  }
  else{
    location.port=8080;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Location Object of js

```
location.port
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `location` in debugger you will get `host` `hostname` `href`  `origin`  `pathname` `port` `protocol` and many more values