# How to detect that is Gatsby serving the build output?

Tags: build, environment-variables, gatsby, production-environment

I would like to know if it is possible and how to detect if the code running is gatsby's `build` output served by `gatsby serve`.
When I launch `gatsby serve` the browser opens on `localhost:9000/`, I would need to change code based on some kind of environment variable or another way. I am looking for the most idiomatic way to do it, if possible not some hack like reading the `window.location` object if possible.
Thanks in advance

Comment: To add a bit of context I asked this because I am using [CookieBot](https://www.cookiebot.com/) with the `data-blockingmode="auto"` attribute enabled. That works only on the domain I configured on cookiebot. Being on a free plan I can only set one domain and therefore I cannot add `localhost:9000`. Being the domain not recognized by cookiebot all my/gatsby javascript doesn't even execute when I run `gatsby serve`, therefore I cannot really see whether the production build is working before deploying it. It took me 4 days to understand this stupid bug.. :(, and basically there was no bug

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction for an issue I was having. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `gatsby build`, Gatsby creates a production ready build of your project in the `public` folder of your project. That means that you can take the `public` folder and deploy the code to a http server. You cannot "detect" any special properties from this code. `gatsby build` is `gatsby build`.

The only way I see is detecting the use of the standard `gatsby serve` port number `:9000` when you `gatsby serve`. See the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/port).

You can get [location props](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/location-data-from-props/) from the reach/router API that Gatsby implements. I am not sure if it implements the same methods as mentioned in the Mozilla documentation. You should try this.

```
const index = ({ location }) => {

  console.log(location.port);

  // ...
}
```

As an alternative you can parse the URL string as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37519587/3689364).

Comment: thanks for taking time to reply. Yes I am aware that the build folder is the one that is on the production live website. Your solution is what I thought as well, reading the location... I'll wait a bit to see if there is some mechanism built in in Gatsby to detect that is `gatsby serve` running, if I don't get any other response I'll mark your reply as the right answer.